# Taking screenshots of a ThreeJS Animation using the toDataUrl method is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Here is my client code :

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true,
    precision: "highp",
});
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
renderer.setPixelRatio((window.devicePixelRatio) ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0.0);
renderer.autoClear = false;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var circle = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(circle);

var geom = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(12, 5);

const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: loader.load('./earth.png'),
});

var planet = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
planet.scale.x = planet.scale.y = planet.scale.z = 10;
circle.add(planet);

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight();
scene.add(ambientLight);

async function animate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        circle.rotation.y -= 0.0020;
        // skelette.rotation.y += 0.0020;
        renderer.clear();
        renderer.render(scene, camera); 
        resolve();
    });
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

async function takeScreenshot() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var imageData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/png');
            image64.push(imageData);   

            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve();
                }, 1000 / fps);
            });
        }
        resolve();
    });
}

function sendCapture() {
    var data = {
        imageArray: image64
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/save-image', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

const fps = 30;


var image64 = [];
await animate();
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    await takeScreenshot();
    sendCapture();
});
```

Here is my server code :

```js
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express()
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(cors(
    {origin: 'http://localhost:5173'}
));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

app.post('/save-image', (req, res) => {
    const imageArray = req.body.imageArray;

    for(let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
        var base64Data = imageArray[i].replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
        fs.writeFile(`./screenshots/image${i}.png`, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
    res.status(200).send('Images saved');
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Here's what i'm trying to achieve :

- I want to take a series of picture of the animation (This is what takeScreenshot does)
- Send them to my server (this is what sendCapture does)
- Save them as .png images

Here are the problems i've encountered :

- Most of the pictures are blank pngs
- Some of them are pictures of the animation
- Some of them are pictures of the animation before the material has loaded